# reading external stdout stream from python

Tags: python, c++, windows, pywin32

I hope I am not getting things mixed up. I want to read stdout stream from an external program (C++ program with an external SDK) which is currently sending its printf commands to a win32 console window (the standard output window from Visual Studio). It is an application (.exe) in the Active (Win32) mode and opens up a separate cmd window to display output (not in the visual studio debugger).

I want to capture the printf commands being executed in that program from an external python script. Most of the solutions/questions, I looked at use Popen, subprocess or ctypes which only work if the C/C++ program is launched from within python (and not separately).

I looked at this question. [How to capture python interpreter and CMD output from Python](http://gotoanswer.stanford.edu/how_to_capture_python_interpreters_andor_cmdexes_output_from_a_python_script-5332035/)

One of the code snippets it has for monkeypatching which says that this can be done is --

```
import sys
import StringIO

s = StringIO.StringIO()

sys.stdout = s

print "hey, this isn't going to stdout at all!"
print "where is it ?"

sys.stderr.write('It actually went to a StringIO object, I will show you now:\n')
sys.stderr.write(s.getvalue())
```

However, this only works with whatever I do from the python interpreter. From my understanding, the sys.stdout is interpreter specific and whenever I set sys.stdout to a StringIO object, it only redirects the stdout(s) launched within that python interpreter to the StringIO object.

How do I extend this capability to other CMD/wind32 windows?

I have looked into launching the C application from within the python, and am aware of how to redirect output using that technique. I am however, looking to launch my C/C++ application separately using Visual Studio and a way for a python script to be able to read content from it.

Any helpful pointers are much appreciated!

EDIT: Edited the description to make the visual studio part a bit more clear.

Comment: In Linux , this can be achieved using `pipes` ,maybe you should look for similar in windows. Typical usage in linux is ` a | python r.py` where `a` is your executable and `r.py` is python program.

Comment: Yes, I am aware of pipes in Linux. I did try to look for windows alternatives, but couldn't find any. I didn't mention it in the question, as it might have steered another (potentially better) solution away if I had asked for an alternative to pipes. Thanks for the suggestion though!

Comment: And unless I am wrong, the pipe still works because both applications are being launched from the same terminal i.e. one command to run both programs in a single instance of terminal (similar situation to the monkeypatch scenario I described above that works within the given interpreter). My described scenario is a bit different.

Comment: The problem with that is that AFAIK there is no way to tell the Visual Studio debugger to launch the process with output piped.  You could tell it to launch `cmd /c a | r.py` but then you'd be debugging `cmd` rather than `a`.

Comment: I am sorry if my question didn't provide enough clarity. The output is not in the Visual Studio debugger. Its in the standard Active (win32) application. The one where the output opens up like an .exe (cmd window).

Comment: @Sylar: was your last comment addressed to me?  Output redirection/piping doesn't depend on the two processes being in the same console.  But there's no way to set up output redirection from a third process.

Comment: Do you need to debug the program?

Comment: Yes it was. I meant to clarify that if there is a way to pipe output to a cmd, which can then be read by a python -- that is an acceptable solution. So, I don't care if cmd is getting debugged or the program, as long as I can share the stdout stream between the c ++ program and the python script (with or without the middle cmd). I am just trying to use the C++ program as a text generator and the python script as reader. Does that make sense?

Comment: OK.  In that case you can run `a.exe | r.py` at the command line, or to launch from Visual Studio, set `cmd /c a.exe | r.py` as the command line to run.  Or you could make `r.py` the command line to run, and have the Python script launch the executable.  You can set the command line in the Project Settings, under "Debugging".

Comment: This is kind of a weird problem. I tried doing what you suggested, but it doesn't work. The C code builds, makes an executable and runs it. It doesn't pipe the output to the python script. However, just to test out, I just did  > abc.txt, and it redirected the output to file. So basically, the pipe isn't working but the ">" operator is?

Comment: I figured out the problem why pipe wasn't working. My C program (exe) is running on an infinite loop and keeps on generating text. The pipe function doesn't pass it to the python file, until the whole program is executed, which is never going to happen since it runs continously. If you have ideas on how to solve this, that'll be great -- otherwise write your pipe comment as an answer and i'll accept it since it answers the original question.